# actionBar is goned when input edittext

Tags: android

My issue is the editText on the tabLayout is child fragment , when i input edittext the actionbar will up and disappear.

I try to add the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or add ScrollView on the fragment xml, they are no working.

I can't find the same issue on internet.
Is anyone can teach me the solution,please.

Parent page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <!--my actionbar is overhere-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="#FF6699">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--Parent Fragment change from here-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Child page:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SubpagesLayout.Homepage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80sp"
            android:id="@+id/genderIcon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo_default_female" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:id="@+id/textNameAges"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="543"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"></LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <!--Child fragment change by the TabLayouts-->
        <!--body_weight_fragment is one of the tabs-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutHomePage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <view
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

body_weight_fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
        <!--input editText will let actionbar disappear-->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editHeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="cm"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCaculate"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_pink"
            android:text="caculate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editWeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="kg"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="show result"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try `adjustResize` instead of `adjustPan`

Comment: I try it too,the setting is no working for body_weight_fragment . It just works for parent fragment not child fragment on the tabLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try it in `manifest`: add (adjustResize + adjustPan) for parent activity

```
        <activity
           android:name="main"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . I try , it's not working for body_weight_fragment , the actionbar disappear.

Comment: do you tried above codes for `body_weight_fragment `'s activity?

Comment: It's fragment not activity . It attached to a activity and i try set the windowSoftInputMode on that activity . It's working for other fragment,but not for  body_weight_fragment , i think the problem is tabhost ,but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself,i have to use scrollView include the toolaBar.Just like above

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="#FF6699">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </ScrollView>
```